# CPU temperature goes high when playing video in a browser - what can I do?

Tags: video, power-management, cpu, browser, overheating

My laptop is overheating almost 90 degrees. This doesn't seem normal with only a browser running.

I used an answer by [Bernard Wei](https://askubuntu.com/users/398808/bernard-wei) to find out what was triggering my overheating problem

> Try running powertop to see which is the offending app.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install powertop
> sudo powertop
> ```

Power is consumed much more when I play a video in a browser. This doesn't happen when I play a video in VLC or Krita or GIMP or netbeans xampp etc.

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Go to system monitor and find the process with high cpu usage.

Comment: Thank you, Basil K Y,  that was the first thing I've done. More over heating comes when browsers are used (Mozzilla, Chromium) other high load apps do not cause the same effect.  4Example VLC or Krita or GIMP or netbeans xampp etc.

Comment: I suggest adding this comment to your question. You can [edit] it.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: What's your computer's graphics adapter and graphics adapter driver? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a`, and `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0300]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster This doesn't depend on adapter.

Comment: @Pilot6: Some combinations of graphics adapter and driver provide (partial) hardware acceleration during video playback in browsers (or rather the browser supports the adapter-driver combo). My CPU alone certainly can't render 1080p AVC videos fluently in software only but they still work in Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: In Chromium it is disabled, unless you enable it using `chrome://flags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that browsers don't support hardware video decoding on Linux, but other players, like VLC, do.

That's why when you are playing video in a browser, it requires more CPU power and more heat is generated.

You can enable hardware video decode in some browsers, but it is not guaranteed to work smoothly on Linux.

Comment: Thank you  Pilot6 can it cause that significant load difference? Like 80-85% between  when I only play video in browser higher than I edit the same video for example in audacity ?

Comment: Yes, it can. It depends on video resolution.

Comment: @MaxKhodonin Instead of writing "solved" in the title accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left. It will accept the answer.